# To create a custom table by getting values from a dynamicaly created table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net

[image: This is the dynamically created table the numbers in columns from L1-L6 are td elements rest are th]

what I want is on save click to show another table like below where the second column(Questions) has sub-columns depending maximum L value a row has:

unit       Question

unit1      23(L1)

unit2      23(L3)

unit3      24(L3)

unit4      6(L2)
unit4      10(L4)

unit5      7(L1)
unit5      10(L6)

unit6      10(L2)
unit       7(L4)

```
var x = [];
    function getval() {
        var trs = $('#DyanmicTable3 tr:not(:first-child):not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)');
        var trs1 = $('#DyanmicTable3 tr:last-child');
        var lastTotalElement = $('#DyanmicTable3 tr:nth-last-child(2)');
        console.log(trs1);
        for (let i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
            const total = Array.from(trs)
                .reduce((acc, tr) => x.push(Number(tr.children[i].textContent)), 0);
            ;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    }
```

this is wt i got so far getting values in an array

Answer (score 0):

```
function GenerateTable() {

        var grid = new Array();
        grid.push(["Unit", "Marks", "Bloom Level"]);
        var tb = $('#DyanmicTable3:eq(0) tbody ');
        tb.find("tr:not(:first-child):not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)").each(function (index, element) {
            var colValtst;
            $(element).find('th:not(:first-child):not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child)').each(function (index, element) {
                colValtst = $(element).text();
            });

            $(element).find('td').each(function (index, element) {
                var colVal = $(element).text();
                let y = $(element).index();

                if (colVal != '') {
                    console.log("    Value in  " + colValtst + " : " + colVal.trim() + "  L" + y);
                    //add grid here
                    grid.push([colValtst, colVal.trim(), "L" + y]);
                }
            });
        });
        //Build an array containing Customer records.
       
       
       // $('#save').attr('href', 'AddQuestions.aspx?val1=' + grid + '');
    

        //Create a HTML Table element.
        var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
        table.border = "1";

        //Get the count of columns.
        var columnCount = grid[0].length;

        //Add the header row.
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = grid[0][i];
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
        }

        //Add the data rows.
        for (var i = 1; i < grid.length; i++) {
            row = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = grid[i][j];
            }
        }

        var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
        dvTable.innerHTML = "";
        dvTable.appendChild(table);
```